# Getting an array from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a summernote editor and trying to implement the "mention" feature by pulling usernames from a database.

```
match: /\B@(\w*)$/,                     
            mentions:function(keyword, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                    url: document.location.origin+"/topic/groupusers/"+topic_cat,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(callback) {                       
                        callback = $(callback).filter('.mentiondata').text();                           
                    }       
                });
            },


            search: function (keyword, callback) {
                callback($.grep(this.mentions, function (item) {
                    return item.indexOf(keyword) == 0;
                  }));
            },
            content: function (item) {
                return '@' + item;
            }
```

The mention attribute needs to have this format:
`mentions: ['jayden', 'sam', 'alvin', 'david'],`

when I console.log `callback` inside the success function that's what I get. However, it doesn't work on search event and gives me  `item is undefined` error

Comment: Where do you call search? It looks like you aren't handling the async callback properly.

Comment: Are y getting mentions in search function. `this.mention` what result?

Comment: @PrashantTapase, it outputs the whole function

Comment: Also, your success callback seems to be broken. All you do is reassign the local `callback`. On second thought, that dupe target may be wrong. I suspect async is causing part of your problems here, but the code otherwise has problems too.

Comment: @Grasper instead of assiging value to callback, return value.. `return $(callback).filter('.mentiondata').text();`

Comment: @PrashantTapase, that didn't help.

Comment: you've got too many variables named callback. Could be a scoping problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass keyword or your parameters in mention function while search.
2. Return value of success in mentions function

> ```
>  match: /\B@(\w*)$/,
>   mentions: function(keyword) {
>     $.ajax({
>       url: document.location.origin + "/topic/groupusers/" + topic_cat,
>       type: 'GET',
>       success: function(result) {
>         return $(result).filter('.mentiondata').text();
>       }
>     });
>   },
>   search: function(keyword, callback) {
>     callback($.grep(this.mentions(keyword), function(item) {
>       return item.indexOf(keyword) == 0;
>     }));
>   },
>   content: function(item) {
>     return '@' + item;
>   }
> ```

[Sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/8a58hd39/)

Comment: I'm getting `a is undefined` in  jquery.min.js